# Global "Text" color and "TextInput" text color

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-text

I've started to work with react-native few days ago and after some extensive search I weren't able to find answers for 2 (simple?) questions:

1. How can I change the color of ALL **Text** components in react-native?
   What are the best practices? Creating an own Text component with
   styling and reusing it everywhere?
2. Change the default text color of **TextInput**. I managed to change the
       placeholder color, and also the underline color in android, but I
       can't find anything on how to change the input text color (stays
       black).
3. Can I change the font / text color for **everything** anyhow? This
   option seems to be missing.

Thanks for any help and cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get consistent styling of `Text` elements (or any other basic element used in a React Native app) our team has started building out a library of components for our app that match the styles and naming of the style guide put together by our design team.

For example your text component would look like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import ReactNative from 'react-native';    

export default class Text extends Component {

  getProps() {
    const { fontSize, fontWeight } = this.props;
    return {
      fontSize,
      fontWeight,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactNative.Text {...this.getProps()}>{this.props.children}</ReactNative.Text>
    );
  }
}

Text.propTypes = {
  fontSize: PropTypes.oneOf([
    25,
    20,
    15,
  ]),
  fontWeight: PropTypes.oneOf([
    'normal',
    'bold',
  ]),
};

Text.defaultProps = {
  fontSize: 20,
  fontWeight: 'normal',
};
```

Creating your text component this way you can define what styles are available and show developers warning if they don't use a valid style with the `PropTypes` definitions.

We also wanted components in this library to be able to be easily referenced from whatever file you needed them in and so we gave the main library file a name with the `providesModule` comment that some of the internal React Native components use.

The main library file looks something like this.

```
/**
 * @providesModule AppNameLibrary
 */

module.exports = {
    get Text() { return require('./Text').default; },
};
```

Then you just need to import it in whatever component file you need the custom Text component.

```
import { Text } from 'AppNameLibrary';
```

That is one way to do it. Not sure if it's the best way, but it's a good way our team has come to build out components so they are designed consistently in a way that matches our style guide.

As far as changing the text color of the Android TextInput component, just assigning a `color: 'orange'` as a style, changed the text to orange for me. We're using RN 0.28 at this point.

Comment: The Text component does not accept a fontSize nor a fontWeight prop.
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text

Answer (score 6):

You can set global text color in android

Step 1. First open `styles.xml` file. file location `/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

Step 2. Add this line inside style tag
`<item name="android:textColor">{Set your color}</item>`

Like this

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Create your own `Text` component with the default styling you desire, and reuse it everywhere. (Like you mentioned)
2. Create a `StyleSheet` object that is accessible globally and use it in every `Text` component.

I think #1 is the best option. Despite the overhead of swapping all your `<Text/>` out, it offers better flexibility in your project's future.

There is no way to change all existing `Text` components unless you create a branch of the `react-native` library and modify the source code for `Text`. I do not recommend this method.

Comment: Do you know how I can define such components in an external file and import them in my index.android.js?

Comment: Found it as "reusable react component" https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html.