# Extend TextInput for customization of default font and text color in React Native like in Java

Tags: javascript, android, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to make a "TypefaceTextInput" that will have a particular font and text color and will replace all TextInput in react native. This is so that I don't have to declare the font and text color everytime. Is there any way to do it?

I am new to react-native, but familiar with android in java and kotlin.
If you can answer with an analogy to how we did it in java or kotlin, that would be very helpful.

Found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877503/5689605) which says

> a library of components for our app that match the styles and naming of the style guide put together by our design team

But I think there will be extra nested components if we use this. Is there any way we can extend TextInput and do the needful in the child class?

Comment: Try use android styles.xml to define it, its same thing in android.

Answer (score 2):

**Check this module** https://github.com/Ajackster/react-native-global-props

I have used it as

```
import {
  setCustomTextInput,
  setCustomText,
} from 'react-native-global-props';

// Setting default styles for all Text components.
const customTextProps = {
  style: {
    fontFamily: 'DINPro'
  },
};
```

To add a custom font you can use the following tutorial https://medium.com/@kswanie21/custom-fonts-in-react-native-tutorial-for-ios-android-76ceeaa0eb78